# Need help understanding a CSP Report and set the right frame-ancestor url

Tags: security, iframe, outlook, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am trying to include my web application as an Office add-in. The add-in includes my app using an iframe so I need to adjust the 'Content Security Policy' headers of my app to make it work.

Currently the value of the header is `content-security-policy: frame-src 'self' ; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';`. If I set the header to `content-security-policy: frame-src 'self' * ; frame-ancestors 'self' *; object-src 'none';` everything is working fine but I don't want to allow everyone to include my app using an iframe.

So I tried to restrict using something like `content-security-policy: frame-src 'self'  https://outlook.live.com; frame-ancestors 'self' https://outlook.live.com ; object-src 'none';` but that does not work. Chrome's JS console says : *Refused to frame 'https://auth-recette-broc.kinexo.fr/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://outlook.live.com".*

And the 'csp report' is:

```
{
  "document-uri": "https://auth-mywebsite.xx/",
  "referrer": "https://yy-mywebsite.xx/",
  "violated-directive": "frame-ancestors",
  "effective-directive": "frame-ancestors",
  "original-policy": "frame-src 'self'  https://outlook.live.com; frame-ancestors 'self' https://outlook.live.com ; object-src 'none';",
  "disposition": "report",
  "blocked-uri": "https://auth-mywebsite.xx/",
  "status-code": 0,
  "script-sample": ""
}
```

I do not understand this csp-report

1. Why the url of the parent frame URI (https://outlook.live.com) does not appear as `document-uri` ?
2. Why the frame is refused when the `document-uri` and `blocked-uri` attributes are identical and `self` is allowed to frame ?
3. How to know the expected url as frame-ancestor to allow framing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the url of the parent frame URI (https://outlook.live.com) does not appear as document-uri ?

The `frame-ancestors` directive is special - it acts to the parent page, while other directives act on page itself (which published the CSP).
Therefore in case of `frame-ancestors` violation, the `document-uri` is an Url of [frame itself](https://csplite.com/csp/test221/#document-uri) (it publishes CSP).

> Why the frame is refused when the document-uri and blocked-uri attributes are identical and self is allowed to frame ?

**`blocked-uri`** in case of `frame-ancestors` is browser depend:

- Chrome shows as `blocked-uri` an URI of locked container(iframe) itself.
- Firefox takes `blocked-uri` from top-level window (but for nesting level >1 Firefox has a bug and sends an empty `blocked-uri`).

So, in Chrome `blocked-uri` will equal to the `document-uri`.

As I understand, you have a `https://yy-mywebsite.xx` page which embeds `https://auth-mywebsite.xx/`.
The `https://auth-mywebsite.xx/` page publishes a CSP `frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';`
In this case `'self'` means `https://auth-mywebsite.xx/` therefore embedding into `https://yy-mywebsite.xx` is not allowed. You have to have at least `frame-ancestors 'self' https://yy-mywebsite.xx; object-src 'none';`

> How to know the expected url as frame-ancestor to allow framing ?

The `frame-ancestors` directive checks all ancestors (the entire upstream chain of parents), not only nearest parent. Therefore you have to specify all hosts for which embeds your iframe is allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this accurate answer. Actually, I have to use this CSP value `frame-ancestors 'self' https: //yy-mywebsite.xx https://outlook.live.com; object-src 'none';` to make it works. It makes sense but I missed this point